# Excel if statement to R codes

Tags: r, excel

I am new to R and trying to use R to run the report I am currently doing in excel. Most of the topics here have been so helpful to me translating excel formula to R codes, however, I am struggling to generate codes for below excel if statement

```
=IF(AND(G2="SEA",OR(F2="FCL",F2="BCN")),W2*40,IF(G2="AIR",X2/1000*66,""))
```

- G Column corresponds to Container/Product
- F Column corresponds to Transport Mode
- AI and AJ correspond to the volumes associated to each Transport mode

Appreciate all the help. Thanks

Here's the link to [data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f31Le.jpg) exported to R

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do a nested `ifelse` after reading the dataset

```
df1 <- read.csv("yourfile.csv", stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
ifelse(df1[,7]=="SEA" & df1[,6] %in% c("FCL", "BCN"),
        df1[,35]*40, ifelse(df1[,7]=="AIR", df1[,36]*66, NA))
```

NOTE: Here we are referring to numeric index for extracting the columns as a reproducible example was not showed.

Comment: Don't know why this was downvoted as `ifelse` is the right function

Comment: Thanks akrun, i edited the formula so it will look at the raw data instead. I tried to run the formula you've provided by seems I still encounter error, TMR_Report$Miles<-ifelse (TMR_Report[,7]=="SEA") & TMR_Report[,6] %in% c("FCL", "BCN"),
Error: unexpected ',' in "TMR_Report$Miles<-ifelse (TMR_Report[,7]=="SEA") & TMR_Report[,6] %in% c("FCL", "BCN"),"
> TMR_Report[,23]*40, ifelse(TMR_Report[,7]=="AIR",TMR_Report[,24]/1000*66, NA))
Error: unexpected ',' in "TMR_Report[,23]*40,"

Comment: @Roland Also showing an image will not be helpful as I cannot copy your data from image.  Please use `dput` to show a small reproducible example.

Comment: Thanks akrun will do your suggestion

Comment: @Roland THere was a typo `)`.  it shouldn't be there. i.e. `-ifelse (TMR_Report[,7]=="SEA" &`

Comment: Thanks you so much akrun, really appreaciate your help, it's all working fine now